# Unreal Stereo Capture with Material post process

Tags: video-capture, unreal-engine4

We are using Panoramic Capture plugin to capture stereo pictures of our product, but it doesn't handle our Material post process effect.

We read from https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/tech-blog/capturing-stereoscopic-360-screenshots-videos-movies-unreal-engine-4 : "Note: You may need to force the capture component to have a ViewState for certain post effects (e.g. material effects) to work" but doesn't understand how this works.

What is this View State? How to setup the ComponentCapture View State to correctly render the Post effect Material?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Quite the same here https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/88754-add-viewstate

Comment: /** 
The view state holds persistent scene rendering state and enables occlusion culling in scene captures.


 * Class used to reference an FSceneViewStateInterface that allows destruction and recreation of all FSceneViewStateInterface's when needed. 
 * This is used to support reloading the renderer module on the fly.
 */
class FSceneViewStateReference